# Import class from development pods with CocoaPods

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, build, cocoapods

I get a little older project from another developer and I should fix some issues and add new features. The project is mainly written in ObjC and is using CocoaPods as dependency manager. Previous developer create his own pod in Development Pods and it contains mainly business logic for application. So I needed add some classes there like RCZMortgage. But when I try to use it in main project I get problem:

```
'RCZMortgage.h' file not found
```

So I was thinking that I must update pod. So I use command `update pod` for that one development pod but after that I started have problem with `Bridging-Header.h` and that files in there can't be found (I don't know if update fix previous problem or just bring more). Previous developer start creating a few classes in swift.

Bridging-Header.h looks like this:

```
#import "RCZAdvertisementBadge.h"
#import "UIView+Centering.h"
#import "UIColor+CustomColors.h"
#import "UIView+Sizing.h"
#import "SDWebImageManager+AutoScale.h"
#import <SDWebImageManager.h>
#import "RCZImageUrlBuilder.h"
```

In podfile there is:

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
```

but there isn't `use_frameworks!`

I'm not sure which informations you need to help me. What files should I write here to help me. So any comments and answers are welcome. I can't contact previous developer so I am asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check weather pod dependencies are correctly matched in build settings.
Give correct pod path, clean the code and try once more.

Comment: I am not sure if I know if dependencies are correctly matched or not. And when you say try once more you mean update pod or just build project?

Comment: Don't think there is a need for pod update , just building would do.

Answer (score -1):

you should check this tutorial for pod file [How to Use CocoaPods](https://www.raywenderlich.com/97014.)

Hope this will help you.